# Parsing JSON in Mule?

Tags: json, mule

I'm trying to read a value inside a JSON string.

The payload from getValue is as simple as :
{ 'result': 'new_value' }

When I try to log the result it prints null

My code is:

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.new_value]" source="#[json:result]">

  <flow-ref name="getValue" />

</enricher>

  <logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO"
    message="new value #[flowVars.new_value]" />

 <flow name="getValue">

     <http:request config-ref="http-request-tts" path="get_value" method="POST">
      </http:request>

    <!-- Here the payload is of type org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream -->

     <object-to-string-transformer/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer />

  </flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `<object-to-string-transformer/>` after `http:request` and
You need to do the following in enricher:-

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.new_value]" source="#[message.payload.result]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
            <flow-ref name="getValue" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
             <json:json-to-object-transformer  returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
       </processor-chain>
 </enricher>
<logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO"  message="authorization_token #[flowVars.new_value]" />
```

But remember, your Json should be in the format :- `{ "result": "new_value"}` and not `{ 'result': 'new_value' }`

Comment: I tried but without object-to-string i receive the error: No serializer found for class org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException). Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream

Comment: without removing object-to-string it works!! thanks!